# Jpa join to get inheriting class by base class

Tags: java, jpa

I have 3 entities.

```
@Entity(name = "a")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class A{
 //things
}

@Entity(name = "b")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "bbb")
class B extends A{
 //things
}

@Entity(name = "c")
class C{
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "A")
 private A a;
}
```

This is a method somewhere in a dao. And I have to access B class somehow through its base class

```
some_method(Root<C> c){
 c.join('a') // this is where i am stuck.
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to me, you want to define abstract "some_method" in class A, and implement the method in B class. It what I do

Comment: I might have spelled it wrong. Its not about the method that i want to access. Some method is in a dao and I need to access class B as it will contain further reference to other entities.

Comment: why wouldnt you add relationship B in C? set to FetchType.LAZY

Comment: because C has to use the base class as it has to save data for all the classes that Extend A. And adding the relationship that you mention would result me having tons of relations in the same class.

Comment: A should not know about B.  basic OOD. You have options to cast to appropriate type. Or create a helper class to manage the instances or do what ever you like.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you have a problem in design. It shouldn't happened when you need to access B from A. It will bite you in the long run.